# Notice: Undefined index: oauth_consumer in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Setup/Declaration/Schema/Db/SchemaBuilder.php

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.4

After migration from linode to AWS, While using the bin/magento setup:upgrade command, getting below error.

```
Notice: Undefined index: oauth_consumer in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Setup/Declaration/Schema/Db/SchemaBuilder.php on line 152
```

What could be the issue? Please help.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this in the end?

Comment: check this please https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/368409/55221

Answer (score 1):

Not sure its a permissions issues - perhaps the `oauth_consumer` database table is missing after DB migration. This can happen if MySql versions or configs are different. e.g default values for TIMESTAMP fields.

Recreate the missing table by executing this query...

```
CREATE TABLE `oauth_consumer` (
  `entity_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Entity ID',
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp() COMMENT 'Created At',
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' ON UPDATE current_timestamp() COMMENT 'Updated At',
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Name of consumer',
  `key` varchar(32) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Key code',
  `secret` varchar(32) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Secret code',
  `callback_url` text DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Callback URL',
  `rejected_callback_url` text NOT NULL COMMENT 'Rejected callback URL',
  PRIMARY KEY (`entity_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `OAUTH_CONSUMER_KEY` (`key`),
  UNIQUE KEY `OAUTH_CONSUMER_SECRET` (`secret`),
  KEY `OAUTH_CONSUMER_CREATED_AT` (`created_at`),
  KEY `OAUTH_CONSUMER_UPDATED_AT` (`updated_at`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='OAuth Consumers';
```

Answer (score 0):

Run command
$ chmod R 777 var/generated/pub/static